# joins eliminating nested queries

Tags: sql

how can I rewrite the query below as a join that eliminates the nested query.

```
SELECT Company, State2 
FROM Customers
WHERE Id IN 
   (SELECT CustomerId 
    FROM Orders 
    WHERE ((ShipDate BETWEEN '2004-01-1'AND'2004-12-31')AND(Shipping>5.0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.Company,
        a.State2 
FROM    Customers a
        INNER JOIN Orders b
            ON a.Id = b.CustomerId
WHERE   b.ShipDate BETWEEN '2004-01-01' AND '2004-12-31'
        AND b.Shipping > 5.0
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: The query you have posted still uses nested queries

Comment: if that's the case, how can you `JOIN` the two tables without *joining* them?

Comment: that is what I am trying to figure out because I am not supposed to use nested queries